# MessageBox aparece duas vezes

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Tenho o seguinte código que é acionado por `Handles Button1.Click`.

```
Dim X, Cf As Double
    Dim A, B, C, D, J As String
    A = TextBox2.Text
    B = TextBox3.Text
    C = TextBox4.Text
    D = TextBox9.Text
    J = ComboBox2.Text
    If J = "K" Then
        If W5() = "K" Then
            If A = "" Then : C1() : Else : X = TextBox2.Text : End If
        ElseIf W6() = "K" Then
            If B = "" Then : C1() : Else : X = TextBox3.Text : End If
        ElseIf W7() = "K" Then
            If C = "" Then : C1() : Else : X = TextBox4.Text : End If
        ElseIf W8() = "K" Then
            If D = "" Then : C1() : Else : X = TextBox5.Text : End If
        End If
        If X <> Nothing Then
            Cf = ((X * 78) / 94) / 100
        End If
    End If
```

Sendo `C1()` uma mensagem de aviso quando o `W (5 a 8)` escolhido for vazio .
Meu problema está em que ao o `W` ser vazio a MessageBox de `C1()` Aparece duas vezes, se o `W` não estiver vazio tudo ocorre como programado.
Este é o código de minha MessageBox:

```
Public Function C1()
    MessageBox.Show("Informe o valor!", "Atenção", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
End Function
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar aqui? Respostas em C# também são aceitas.

Peço desculpas a todos que tiraram um pouco de seu tempo para ajudar-me, o código estava sendo disparado duas vezes, agora voltou ao normal.  Agradeço a todos pela ajuda.

Comment: Que `W`? Aí não tem `W` algum. Só com este trecho não tem como ajudar.

Comment: @bigown seria W5, W6, W7, W8

Comment: A String `K` só pode aparecer em um dos quatro `W`, e onde ela estiver o W referido será indicado como verificação na TextBox referente.

Comment: Eu acho que está faltando código no exemplo. O que tem na pergunta parece estar certo.

Comment: Isso que você postou é um if elseif, ele não vai nunca entrar em dois mesmo que mais de um W seja "k", você já fez um debug nesse if para ver onde ele está entrando? Provável que seja em outro lugar o seu problema.

Comment: Eu fiz debug @Ricardo e dá a mesma coisa, sem informar erro algum, fiz testes com k estando uma vez em W5 e outra em W6, porém quando ele verifica a TextBox referente aquele W (quando ela esta vazia) ele dá a mensagem duas vezes.

Comment: Qual seria o evento que está disparando isso? Coloca isso também na pergunta. Talvez esteja disparando duas vezes.

Comment: É disparado por Button1.Click @Ricardo

Comment: @AlexNunes, Que bom que seu problema foi resolvido. Agora, crie uma resposta o que você fez para resolver seu problema.. Isso pode ser útil para outra pessoa no futuro.

Comment: Este problema já foi resolvido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mensagem estava aparecendo duas vezes porque o código citado era executado dentro de uma função após clicar em botão do aplicativo, o problema foi que eu não percebi que o mesmo botão chamava uma outra função que executava o mesmo código.

É como eu estivesse clicando duas vezes. Então removi o `Handles Button1.Click` repetido em uma funções e tudo ficou certo.